# Is there a way to copy specific ranges in one sheet to specific ranges in another sheet based on a varying string as a signal?

Tags: excel, vba, range, copy-paste

I'm looking for ideas in VBA and whether my challenge is even possible.

I have a worksheet *"Data"* with a range consisting of a varying number of rows, but a fixed number of 9 columns. In one of the columns there is name of each paper, e.g. SPX US 04/17/20 C2790 Index.

The target is to copy each 9 columns to the next sheet, *"Calculation and Output"*, where a large dataset of +5000 rows, have some of the same papers in them.

I can copy all the rows from data to the second sheet, but I don't know if its even possible with VBA to copy the input from *"Data"* and match the 9 columns from each paper with the columns for the same paper on the second sheet.

Basically, what I have is this (works OK, but it doesn't copy information to to each of the right ticker names):

```
Sub CopyTest()

    Dim llastrow, lPasteColumn As Long

    Set DataSPX = wsData.Range("F7")
    lPasteColumn = 2

    DataSPX.Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    wsCalcAndOutput.Range("M5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

End Sub
```

I've attached two pictures. Picture 1 is the data that will be copied. Picture 2 is the data, that has been copied, but as I've highlighted in red, there is no connection between the "complete ticker" name.

Any ideas and inputs are welcome!

All the best,
Christoffer

[Picture 1: Data to be copied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzAJs.png)
[Picture 2: Copied data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYwaD.png)

Comment: VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH or XLOOKUP not work?

Comment: I havent tried those - but thank you for the suggestions. I'll check them out!

Comment: I think XLOOKUP might work - but I only have Office 365 on my work computer, so I'll have to try it tomorrow - thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Then use `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX/MATCH`.